# Problem with an equation.

Tags: problem-solving

I have this equation:

v*t-(u*g*t^2)/2 = d

And I'm having trouble solving it for `t`. Mathematica gave me two results,

`t -> (v+-Sqrt[-2 d g u+v^2])/(g u)`

Have no idea how it got it.
I did manage to get to
`t = (d+0.5u*g*t)/v
or t^2 = (v*t-d)/(0.5u*)`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation can be written as $-ugt^2+2vt-2d=0$. The quadratic formula then gives $t=\dfrac{-2v\pm\sqrt{4v^2-4(-ug)(-2d)}}{-2ug}$, which is equivalent to what Mathematica gave you.